# How to put R objects in manually allocated memory?

Tags: r, memory-management

I am developing a function in C for R package and I need to initialize R numeric vector in manually allocateed memory that is not garbage collected.

The standard function allocVector(REALSXP, XXX) allocates memory for me and initializes the object. I have already an allocated piece of memory, I need to initialize R object in this memory and return it to userspace.

Algorithm I am trying to follow

1. Allocate memory myself (actually it is a memory mapped file)
2. Put a R object (standard R numerical vector) in this memory (How?)
3. Prevent garbage collector from trying to collect it (How?)
4. Register finalizer for this object
5. Return R object user can use it
6. Get a notification that object is no longer referenced and deallocate the object

Answer (score 4):

Your problem starts with 1. as the [Writing R Extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) tells you (in its cryptic ways, see [Section 5.9.2](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Allocating-storage)) that you *must* use R's memory "pool" for objects that you hand back to R.  How else could R release the object's memory if it doesn't control the access?

Unless you use external pointers, which are also covered (somewhat) in the same manual, and some other places (other questions here, r-devel archives, several packages, ...).

And the R package [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) pretty much covers exactly this (also see the [related bigmemory website](http://www.bigmemory.org/).  You could, if you're so inclined, start with bigmemory and derive a package 'mmapmemory' from it.  Oh, and there is a package [mmap](http://cran.r-project.org/package=mmap) but maybe you knew that already.

Comment: then I need away to hack in R garbage collector. My package doesn't have to be portable - it will be run on dedicated R instance and hardware

Comment: Needn't be portable is quite likely a very bad plan.  As Dirk mentions, you can't do what you want without some fancy hacking.  Is it possible, yep.  Will someone go to the lengths to explain it - probably not.  I've asked, been shown, and quite frankly wish I hadn't seen it ;-) For the record, I am the author of mmap for R as well.  Good luck!